# Jupyter Notebook Cannot Run without Root

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04, kernel-module, jupyter-irkernel

Have been using jupyter notebook with python3 for almost a year, never had this issue. All of a sudden, I cannot run jupyter notebook without a being a root user. This is how the error I face looks like

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog-0.8.3-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I tried multiple uninstall/reinstall of pip3, jupyter, ipykernel etc. but nothing helped. I read somewhere it has something to do with directory permissions at my home, and hence I changed the owner of my home directory to myself as a user (not root) recursively. Still no luck.

If it helps, here are some extra details.

This is the output of `jupyter kernelspec list`

```
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
Available kernels:
  pyspark3kernel    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark3kernel
  pysparkkernel     /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pysparkkernel
  python3           /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  sparkkernel       /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkkernel
```

This is the `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` file

```
{
"display_name": "Python 3",
"language": "python",
"argv": [
"/usr/bin/python3",
"-m",
"ipykernel_launcher",
"-f",
"{connection_file}"
]
}
```

Finally, this is the `uname --all` output.

```
Linux hn0-ciabdp 4.4.0-150-generic #176-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 18:56:26 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help will be appreciated. Better still, some reference materials to understand the inner workings of how jupyter connects to python interpreter and what do these settings mean.

Comment: Python 2.7 ??? OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7

Comment: is default version of python somehow changed to python 2.7?

Comment: I do not know. If it did, how do I get it back. Now, after some more tinkering, it is worse. Even the root cannot run jupyter and I get an error saying ImportError: No module named 'IPython.paths'

Comment: In the terminal check python version. python --version

Comment: python --version gives 2.7.12, python3 --version gives 3.5.2. It has always been like that.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2621#issuecomment-312672865 did you check this..